# Inconsistent Import Error in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, psychopy

I just have a quick question about an error I've been getting when I try to import:

```
from psychopy import gui
```

So if I try to import this code in one program I have no problems, however, if I try to import it in another I get:

```
"ImportError: cannot import name gui"
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Why does it work for one problem, but not the other? Also, I feel like it wasn't doing this before, and it just started suddenly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use different virtual environments for both the projects, and if yes, is the package installed in both?

Comment: I think this is correct, when I cut and paste the code from one program to the other it seems to work. But how do I know which virtual environment I am working in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I think Jon's answer is the correct one. If I was right, you should get an error "no module named psychopy".

---

Given that you tagged this question with the `psychopy` tag, my guess is that it works if you run it from the psychopy app and that it doesn't work if you run it from another editor or command line.

The reason is that psychopy is currently shipped as a bundle that comes with it's own python and a lot of modules/dependencies, including psychopy. The system is not made aware of these modules via the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can make them available system-wide by either (1) following the steps outlined [here](http://lindeloev.net/?page_id=216) or (2) use the `conda` based installation described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/psychopy-dev/conda/psychopy-dev/ndOWoiEwDMU/aARq4VaDXBMJ) in the psychopy-dev list. The latter feature is still work in progress but will probably eventually mature to be the default install option.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the other answers are wrong ;-)
I think if you had a different virtual environment or installation then the error in your code would indicate "No module named psychopy"

The fact that it finds something called psychopy but no sub-module called gui is a different problem. Often this occurs if you have a folder or file called psychopy next to you current working directory (eg. next to where you launch the script). Then Python thinks that's the `psychopy` module but can't find `gui` within it.

So, do you have a folder called `psychopy`? Rename it `psychopyStuff`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using different virtual environments for both the projects, and so the package is installed in one virtualenv, and not in the other.

To verify this is the case,  do a `pip freeze` in both the projects and compare the results.

If there is a single environment, the output will be same, otherwise the outputs will be different amongst the two.